# Change images clicking button

Tags: jquery, image, click, src

I can't make this work.... I have to use jquery to change an image when we click on another image; So, I have 4 people and they have 3 images each with their favourite things. There are two images working as buttons; a heart and a plate. By default it has to show the 3 loved things which will show if we click the heart image, if we click in the plate image, it will change those 3 images for 3 images of their favourite food.

### html

```
<div id="steve" class="ourLove">
   <img class="love1" />
   <img class="love2" />
   <img class="love3" />
   <img class="heart" />
   <img class="plate" />
</div>
<div id="betty" class="ourLove">
   <img class="love1" />
   <img class="love2" />
   <img class="love3" />
   <img class="heart" />
   <img class="plate" />
</div>
<div id="glen" class="ourLove">
   <img class="love1" />
   <img class="love2" />
   <img class="love3" />
   <img class="heart" />
   <img class="plate" />
</div>
<div id="maria" class="ourLove">
   <img class="love1" />
   <img class="love2" />
   <img class="love3" />
   <img class="heart" />
   <img class="plate" />
</div>
```

### this is my js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
   jQuery('.plate', this).click(function() {
     jQuery('.love1', this).attr('src', 'images/food1.jpg');
     jQuery('.love2', this).attr('src', 'images/food2.jpg');
     jQuery('.love3', this).attr('src', 'images/food3.jpg');
        return false;
    });
 jQuery('.heart', this).click(function() {
     jQuery('.love1', this).attr('src', 'images/love1.jpg');
     jQuery('.love2', this).attr('src', 'images/love2.jpg');
     jQuery('.love3', this).attr('src', 'images/love3.jpg');
        return false;
    });
  });
```

But seems to do nothing. I thing "this" on click must me wrong, but I've tried to take it off and nothing changes either. It has to do it forever, I mean, if the customer clicks a thousand times each button-image the images will change.

Any help? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vareen's answer makes sense. However, I would clean it up this way:

`jQuery` can actually be presented with a dollar sign `$`, and you shouldn't call the parent for every line, just assign it to a variable. Also `this` is no longer needed in your click functions, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $('.plate').click(function() {
        var $p = $(this).parent(); 
        $p.find('.love1').attr('src', 'images/food1.jpg');
        $p.find('.love2').attr('src', 'images/food2.jpg');
        $p.find('.love3').attr('src', 'images/food3.jpg');
        return false;
    });

    $('.heart').click(function() {
        var $p = $(this).parent(); 
        $p.find('.love1').attr('src', 'images/love1.jpg');
        $p.find('.love2').attr('src', 'images/love2.jpg');
        $p.find('.love3').attr('src', 'images/love3.jpg');
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In this problem we need to identify the user which clicks the plate or heart. So we need to find out the div block from where the click event is triggered and then we can change the images of love1,love2, love3 of that particular div. I have use the following code and it is working fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
    jQuery('.plate', this).click(function() {
      jQuery(this).parent().find('.love1').attr('src', 'images/food1.jpg');
      jQuery(this).parent().find('.love2').attr('src', 'images/food2.jpg');
      jQuery(this).parent().find('.love3').attr('src', 'images/food3.jpg');
      return false;
    });
    jQuery('.heart', this).click(function() {
      jQuery(this).parent().find('.love1').attr('src', 'images/love1.jpg');
      jQuery(this).parent().find('.love2').attr('src', 'images/love2.jpg');
      jQuery(this).parent().find('.love3').attr('src', 'images/love3.jpg');
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hey.. Please provide any response. Did you find my answer correct or not ?